# Restrict user from accessing code inside docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, password-protection, docker-machine

I have created a docker image for my code which is an Django and Deeplearning application and I have to give that image to some client. What I want is that the client should not be permitted to access the code. So is there any chance to password protect the docker image so that the user has to enter the username and password from command line each time before trying to execute any docker command?
Docker version - 19.03.12 / June 18, 2020
Operating system - Ubuntu

Comment: its not possible to protect code from docker image. well you can create docker user account to protect your docker images.

Comment: @ANISHKUMARMOURYA can you please guide me how to create that user account

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can trivially root the host, and can very easily look at any file in any container or image.  Docker doesn't add any protection if you consider your source code "secret" but want to use an interpreted language.  Consider a compiled language (Go, Rust, C++, Java) where you don't need to distribute the actual source code to run the application.